# Return 0 if no row/empty result in mysql

Tags: mysql

is there a way where I can return 0 if i get an empty result in mysql?

```
SELECT t1.amount as Amt
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
ON t1.project_id = t2.id

WHERE t2.proj_name = "Project_Kalinga"
AND t1.date_sent = (SELECT MAX(date_sent) FROM table WHERE project_id = "0123")
```

Currently for the project name 'Project Kalinga' I get an empty result.

Is there a way where from this query even if i get an empty result, I'll just get 0 instead?
So then the output would be like

```
| Amt |
|  0  |
```

Thank You!

Here's the sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c4c5/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can

- create a "Dummy row" with zero
- do a left join to your main query.
- Coalesce the real value and the dummy value

---

```
SELECT Coalesce(t1.amt, d.amount) AS amt 
FROM   (SELECT 0 as amount
        FROM   DUAL) AS d
       LEFT JOIN  
       (SELECT t1.amount AS Amt 
        FROM   table1 AS t1 
               INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 
                       ON t1.project_id = t2.id 
        WHERE  t2.proj_name = "project_kalinga" 
               AND t1.date_sent = (SELECT Max(date_sent) 
                                   FROM   table1 
                                   WHERE  project_id = "0123")) AS t1 
       ON 1 = 1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c4c5/25)

Comment: nevermind, got it. Thanks! just changed  `t1.amount` to `t1.Amt`

Comment: @hearmeroar I also used "table" when I should have used "table1" Thanks for the fiddle btw. It makes everything eaiser

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(t1.amount,0) as Amt
FROM table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.project_id = t2.id AND t2.proj_name = "Project_Kalinga"
WHERE t1.date_sent = (SELECT MAX(date_sent) FROM table WHERE project_id = "0123")
```

Comment: It didn't work for me either. Still getting the error `MySQL returned an empty result set ` and it didn't return any rows

Comment: @hearmeroar: Can you show me some contents of the table, please?

Comment: still didn't work. Here is the requested content http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c4c5/2